# Elasticsearch: distribution of field with regard to other field(s)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch DB with items of the form

```
record = {
            'diagnosis': self.diagnosis,
            'vignette': self.vignette,
            'symptoms': self.symptoms_list,
            'care': self.care_level_string,
            'age': self.age,
            'gender': self.gender
        }
```

I need a query that returns the distribution of `'age'` (float), and another one that returns the distribution of `'gender'` (string with 2 options) with regard to `'care'` (string with 3 options).

Meaning, for example, if the DB had

```
1. care='a', age=1.0, gender='m'
2. care='b', age=2.0, gender='m'
3. care='c', age=1.0, gender='m'
4. care='a', age=1.0, gender='m'
5. care='b', age=2.0, gender='m'
6. care='c', age=3.0, gender='m'
7. care='a', age=3.0, gender='f'
8. care='b', age=3.0, gender='f'
```

then the distribution of `gender` with regard to `care='a'` would return something like

`{'m:2, 'f':1}`

I can't seem to get the correct syntax/understanding

I am using python

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question, I've come up with the below mapping, query and response.

### Mapping

```
PUT medicalrecord
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "diagnosis": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "vignette": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "symptoms": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "care": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "gender":{
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I've created multi-fields for `gender` and `care`. I'd suggest you to go through this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) so that you get to know its relevance.

### Query

Below query is what you are looking for.

It is a combination of simple [Filter Using Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query on `care` followed by [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) over field `gender`.

```
POST medicalrecord/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "care.keyword": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "mf_distribution": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've created a query for `care` having value `a`. You can construct similar queries for other values of it.

Looking at your question, I believe you are just starting out with Elasticsearch. I'd suggest you to spend sometime in reading about [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

Below is how your response would appear for the above query.

### Response

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "mf_distribution" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "m",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "f",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What you want can be seen under `buckets`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will get to this ASAP, test, then accept. THANK YOU. I didn't know how to start reading the doc, and you gave me some pointers

Comment: hey @Gulzar was the above useful. Did it solve what you were looking for?